# .NET Core API single vs multiple instances performance

Tags: scaling, asp.net-core-3.1

From a performance standpoint does it make sense to run multiple instances of a .NET Core API on a single machine?

I'm currently running a .NET Core API via Docker, using Consul and Ocelot. I have two production servers and my API is running on each. I can pretty easily run multiple instances of the API on each server but I'm struggling to find evidence that this offers performance benefits. Will a single instance utilize as much horsepower as is available, so running multiple instances just adds overhead? I realize from a redundancy standpoint it might make sense to run multiple instances per machine, but I'm wondering about performance.